# definition of Fourier coefficient for map of vectorbundles

Tags: fourier-series, vector-bundles, k-theory, topological-k-theory

I am trying to understand the elementary proof of atiyah and bott for bott periodicity(cf. Atiyah's book K-Theory, page 51). In the proof they define fourier coefficients, but I can't see how their definition makes sense.

Let $X$ be a space and let $L$ be a line bundle over $X$. Choose a metric on $L$ and let $S \subset L$ be the unit circle bundle and denote by $\pi: S \rightarrow X$ the projection map. Let $z : S \rightarrow \pi ^*(L)$ be the section given by the diagonal map $s \mapsto (s,s) \in L \times_XS = \pi ^*(L)$. If $E_1,E_2$ are bundles over $X$ and $f\in \Gamma \text{Hom}(\pi ^* E_1, \pi ^* E_2)$ then atiyah and bott define the k'th Fourier coefficient $a_k\in \Gamma \text{Hom}(L^k \otimes E_1, E_2) $ of $f$ as 
$$a_k(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{S_x} f_x \otimes z_x^{-k-1} \text{d}z_x$$ 
But i can't even make sense of $f_x \otimes z_x^{-k-1}$, since $z$ is a section into $\pi ^*(L)$ and the $f$ is a section into a Hom vectorbundle. How am I supposed to tensor them and how is $a_k$ real a section into $\text{Hom}(L^k \otimes E_1, E_2) $?

Answer (score 2):

The section $f$ is of the bundle
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(\pi^*E_1,\pi^*E_2)
= \pi^* \operatorname{Hom}(E_1, E_2)
$$
over the manifold $S$ (not $X$, nota bene). We can tensor this with a power of the section $z$ of the bundle $\pi^*S$ over $S$ (not $X$), and get a section of 
$$
\pi^*(S^{k} \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(E_1,E_2)) 
\subset \pi^*(L^{k} \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(E_1,E_2))
$$ 
over $S$. We can then take the pushforward of this section under $\pi$ and get a section of 
$$
L^{k} \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(E_1,E_2) 
= \operatorname{Hom}(L^{-k} \otimes E_1,E_2)
$$ 
over $X$. The pushforward comes down to exactly the integral over each unit circle. It takes a little work to figure out the details (working out the case where $X$ is a point helps), but it's good practice. (Question 1: Why is the change in sign $k \to -k$ is correct? Question 2: But where does the extra $-1$ in $z^{-k-1}$ come from, Michael? (Hints: Michael - see Arrested Development. For the $-1$, think about the Lebesgue measure on the unit circle from complex analysis.))

It could be worth your time to spend a little while thinking about pullbacks of vector bundles (things like $p^*E \to E$ where $p : E \to X$ is a vector bundle) and the various canonical isomorphisms of vector spaces (like $L^k \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) = \operatorname{Hom}(L^{-k} \otimes V, W)$). It's not particularly complicated stuff, but it takes a while to get used to it. Always remember: the simplest manifold is a point, and a vector space is just a vector bundle over a point. That'll get you plenty of cheap simple examples to practice on.

Comment: Ok, I understand now that $f_xz_x^{-k+1}$ is a section of $\pi^* \text{How}(L^{k+1} \otimes E_1, E_2)$ restricted to $S_x$. Then I wrote out the definition of the pullback to $S_x$ to get that $f_xz_x^{-k+1}$ is a map from $S_x \times L_x^{k+1} \otimes S_x \times E_{1,x} \rightarrow S_x \times E_{2,x}$. But now how to integrate them along $S_x$? Could you give me another hint?

Comment: It's actually $f_x z_x^{-k}$ that's a section of $\pi^*\operatorname{Hom}(L^{-k} \otimes E_1, E_2)$. To calculate the pushforward you need to tensor it with a $1$-form. It just so happens that the unit circle comes with the standard $1$-form $1/2\pi i \cdot dz / z$, which gets you the extra $-1$ in the exponent of $z$.

Comment: ok. Unfortunetaly I don't know anything about differential forms. Could you maybe give me a hint to some literature where they explain stuff like this?

Comment: Hmm... I don't have personal recommendations for this. I picked it up when I was learning complex differential geometry as one of the basics everyone assumes people know. I've heard other people recommend "Geometry of differential forms" by Morita, but I've never read it. You don't need the full theory of differential forms for this anyway (but they're super useful, and worth your time). You can just think of a differential form (a function times $dz$) as something you integrate over a one-dimensional real manifold (the circle, here).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it that you've never seen differential forms but are studying K-theory? Seems a bit like putting the cart before the horse, somehow.

Comment: I am reading the book K-Theory by Atiyah. He claimed at the beginning that no other knowledge than some basic topology and algebra is needed(which until this point proved true, I think). I'll look into that book, thanks!